# Run an iteration in C++ to store variable when certain condition is met

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I  have made a program to store channel number when Channel Value > 0.1.
I have already defined the iteration. 
In loop, the iteration runs on different channels (for example: channel no 1, channel no 2 and so on).
 Then I called an other program to calculate value. It will calculate value for each channel one by one.
My task is to get the channel whose  Channel Value > 0.1. I don't know how to store those channel numbers. It would be highly appreciated if you guys could help me. Thanks.

```
list < int >  GetChannels(Node* node) 
{

 list<int> Channels = GetList(node); //calling a list which I already defined. 
 list<int>::iterator itr;
for (itr=Channels.begin(); itr!=Channels.end(); ++itr) {
    double ChannelValue = CalculateValue(node, *itr); //calling another func
    if (ChannelValue > 0.1) {
```

`

Comment: I have edited the code so that it is readable. Thanks

Comment: it's still not readable! You're missing the body of the `if` statement!

Comment: @sean, I think the question is about what goes in there. My question is what language is this? C++ or c#.

Comment: yeah because that's my question is. I dont know how to store the channel if ChannelValue > 0.1

Comment: yeah exactly Ben. This is my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you create another list to return with the values?

```
list < int >  GetChannels(Node* node) {

   list<int> Channels = GetList(node); //calling a list which I already defined. 
   list<int> output; // Output list.
   list<int>::iterator itr;
   for (itr=Channels.begin(); itr!=Channels.end(); ++itr) {
       double ChannelValue = CalculateValue(node, *itr); //calling another func
       if (ChannelCapacityValue > 0.1) {
            output.insert(*itr);
       }
   }
   return output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ben :)

Answer (score 0):

If I get the exact requirement you just need to build a list by filtering an existing collection over a specific predicate which is `CalculateValue(node, *itr) > 0.1f`.

This seems a task for `std::copy_if`, sort of:

```
list<int> channels;
list<int> filteredChannels;

...

copy_if(channels.begin(), channels.end(), back_inserter(filteredChannels), 
    [node] (const int& value) { return CalculateValue(node,value) > 0.1f; }
);
```

Why reinventing the wheel when STL already provides you with the right facility?

If you don't have access to C++11 lambdas then provide a custom function, eg. `bool isValidChannel(const int& channel) { ... }` but this would require binding the `node` parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much Jack. Your answer is really helpful  :)